# I keep getting this error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, axios

I am creating a sign in page and in my API client class,. I wrote this code that would send a response from the backend to my sign in frontend.

```
static async signIn(user, pass){
  const response = await axios
    .get('http://localhost:8080/signIn', {
      username: user,
      password: pass,
    })

  return response.data;
}
```

Immediately after I wrote it though, this error message popped up on my server:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined**

```
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/Amman/dunder-mifflin/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:42
  39 |  * @public
  40 |  */
  41 | 
> 42 | var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
  43 | 
  44 | /**
  45 |  * Module exports.
View compiled
```

I don't know what caused it or if I typed it wrong, I tried finding ways to fix it but it still gives me the same error. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: That code is fine. The problem would appear to be elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder True. Don't know why my eyes skipped over that.

Comment: Wrong version of node.js maybe? What version of node/npm/express are you using?

Comment: Does this method exist in a scope where the identifier `response` might shadowing express's `response`/`res`?

Comment: @Zac Anger Yes! Forgot to delete that

Comment: @AmmanM welp, I'm stumped. That version of node definitely has that class in the http core lib. One of your other dependencies messing with it? Maybe try clearing out and re-loading: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`. Or whatever the command is on windows.

Comment: @AmmanM awesome, is it fixed then?

Comment: @Zac Anger Yep!